How may I yield outputs (llm tokens) from langgraph nodes?
I am working on an AI agent based on langgraph framework. In the generation node, I should yield the llm generated tokens to frontend and proceed to the END node when generation is done.
However, the way I am receiving the llm tokens is by calling some internal API, so that I think it probably can't be compatible with the astream_event() provided by langgraph.
More specifically, my generation node looks like below:
def generation_node(self, state):
    with requests.post("some api url") as response:
        for chunk in response.iter_content():
            message = chunk
        yield message.decode()

The problem is, when I have yield in this node, it becomes a generator so I can't run this function directly. In the langgraph workflow, the structure is something like:
self.workflow.add_node("generation")
self.workflow.add_edge(start_key="generation", end_key=END)
self.workflow.compile()

So I am stuck here and don't know how to correctly pass my outputs. Thanks anyone for the help!
I tried to use astream_event when receiving the outputs, but the graph itself won't compile
